# CrashlyticsUploadSymbols for Android native library suceeded but no symbols shown in Firebase console?

Tags: android, c++, google-fabric, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to upload native symbols for external native library in Android app. All setup and it seems the crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease succeeded. I checked the crashlytics.log and it says that the .cSYM file 's being generated and uploaded to https://cm.crashlytics.com/api/v3/platforms/android/code_mappings. But when I check the Crashlytics tab in the Firebase console the logs are not resolved i.e. no stack traces to be shown.

I use LLD as default. I thought that this could be the problem - removed it, so started using the default one provided by the NDK, but still no success.

The NDK out dirs are...

```
androidNdkOut '../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj'
androidNdkLibsOut '../build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/release/0/lib'
```

Also tried with stripDebugSymbol folder for androidNdkLibsOut - no success.

Comment: `the logs are missing` - what do you mean by `logs`? There are no crashes? or their symbols are not resolved?

Comment: Not resolved I meant.

Comment: Maybe you have a similar problem to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604617/wrong-native-callstacks

Comment: Yes, it seems you have the same problem. You're using Fabric, right?

Comment: I was using crashlytics for long time, now - a month ago - I linked our project to fabric.

Comment: So you mean it's the same problem with Fabric? I thought it could be a migration issue in Firebase only, in case we assume It's not our fault.

Comment: I had the same problems on fabric.io, I thought that migration to firebase (I followed migration guide on fabric.io) would fix it. Actually this migration does not require lots of changes, its more a migration on the www side, at least from the developer point of view. I have reposted my problem on NDK google groups (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/JO36_-gFnmg/Ietu-lzKAwAJ) with compiler/linker option lists, I suspect there might be some problem with it. I also start to suspect that problems might have started when we moved from gcc to clang, but thats only hypothesis.

Comment: @Plamen, are you using the latest version of LLD?

Comment: I don't know which is the latest LLD version, I used the latest NDK version and just enabled the LLD linker. It seems the problem is the LLD linker. All is working fine with the default linker.