# Firebase Crashlytic does not show stack strace with LLD linker Android App

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

My project is a simple Android game with native C++ code and Java, which uses cmake to compile C/C++ code.
I upload a my native symbols to Firebase Crashlytic (Fabric ago) to catch my crash if they happens.
I follow the instruction [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) to setup the crashlytics.

I found one specific problem: the Crashlytic does not show any stacktrace of my App if I use lld linker for C/C++ code.

Here is the config I set to use LLD
`set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=lld")`

Config in `build.gradle`

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
```

I use `crashlyticUploadSymbolsDebug` to upload Symbols

The log upload is quiet good.

```
2020-03-23 15:02:03.664 [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Crashlytics attempting to upload cSYM files.
2020-03-23 15:02:03.669 [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - POST file: C:\Users\nhut_\.crashlytics\com.crashlytics.tools\app-f5c61bd8c0ab9f7beacd8e312f884ac1970c43e5\debug\csyms\Breakout-aarch64-2cbd7a2add29f8fbff897f89c43ea0d93088c11f.cSYM.gz to URL: https://cm.crashlytics.com/api/v3/platforms/android/code_mappings
2020-03-23 15:02:03.983 [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - POST response: [reqId=c8949d54f956c305a08f1744dabdd9b226b494443224707e] 202
2020-03-23 15:02:03.984 [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - POST file: C:\Users\nhut_\.crashlytics\com.crashlytics.tools\app-f5c61bd8c0ab9f7beacd8e312f884ac1970c43e5\debug\csyms\Breakout-aarch64-b0e07c6b9715755bb3b1d881aefe1777a7dcca11.cSYM.gz to URL: https://cm.crashlytics.com/api/v3/platforms/android/code_mappings
2020-03-23 15:02:04.235 [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - POST response: [reqId=65ed22d3d2111a7dadc5b61109f7d7664dcd86ba58579c9f] 202
2020-03-23 15:02:04.236 [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - cSYM file(s) uploaded.
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

My OS is `Windows 10 1909 64bit, Android Studio 3.5.1, android-ndk-r21`

The devices tested is Pixel 3.

Thanks for your time to read and appreciate with your suggestion.
I found similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848196/crashlyticsuploadsymbols-for-android-native-library-suceeded-but-no-symbols-show) but have no answer until now

Answer (score 1):

we're experiencing a similar issue, no symbols in Crahalytics.

- NDK Version: 21.0.6113669.
- Crashalytics Gradle Plugin: 2.3.0

Linker:

1. LLD - no symbols
2. LLD with linker flag: `-Wl,--no-rosegment` suggested by  Dan Albert within this bug report: https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1196 - no symbols
3. Default linker - no symbols.

We're banging our heads, any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Hello @Max Raskin, do you use the Cmake or third party toolchain to compile C/C++ part on your project? My project is fine with Cmake.

Comment: @seal2002 I'm using the bundled CMake 3.10.x

Comment: Do you use Android App Bundle? What's device you test on? Architecture and Firmware?

Comment: Update: stripDebugDebugSymbols task  which runs llvm-strip tool messes up our already stripped .so, it alters some bits in it therefore making its sha1 incompatible with the sha1 of the unstripped so file.

Comment: Update2: ```packagingOptions { doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/libMyLibrary.so" }``` solved our problem

Comment: Do not strip the so will make the APK bigger and the SO is unsafe?

Comment: I wonder how CMake use the llvm-strip as default? on my project aarch64-linux-android-strip.exe still use as default

Answer (score 0):

We are still using the r20 NDK, and with it and -fuse-ld=lld there was issue with the native Crashlytics, so we just stopped using it and everything is fine now (native stacktraces are resolved properly in Firebase console)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already test with `gold linker` and `default linker`, everything is fine. For some reasons, I want to use `lld linke`r as it optimizes some stuff for company project (linking time reduce from 10 minutes to 2 minutes and more stuff). So I want to know that Fabric noticed that issue happen with their parse tools, or we need to add some specific flag for lld linker.